# MySQL Inserting a record after a specified location in a table

Tags: php, mysql

Consider a mysql table,

```
id |  name  |  content | flag
------------------------------
1 |  name1  |  content1 | 0
2 |  name2  |  content2 | 1
3 |  name3  |  content3 | 0
4 |  name4  |  content4 | 0
```

I want to insert a new record before `name3`

```
5 |  new    |  newc     | 1
```

The Result should be like this,

```
id |  name  |  content | flag
------------------------------
1 |  name1  |  content1 | 0
2 |  name2  |  content2 | 1
5 |  new    |  newc     | 1  <---- new record
3 |  name3  |  content3 | 0
4 |  name4  |  content4 | 0
```

Any MySQL query to do that?

P.S: I'm creating forum... so consider `name3` posts something. The reply for `name3` will be stored before `name3` record as new. On displaying all the contents in the table in the reverse order, i could display the corresponding post and reply using `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: May I know the what is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Better is to add `order` column to sort your resultset as you need to. IMO

Comment: If you have auto incremented primary key which I suppose "id" is in your example. So You can not insert the data before and after certain row. But if its the display that you need to be ordered the way you want you can use order by clause to so on the table columns.

Comment: I'm creating forum... so consider `name3` posts something. The reply for `name3` will be stored before `name3` record as `new`. On displaying all the contents in the table in the reverse order, i could  display the corresponding post and reply using `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: You have three entities users, posts and replies so I think you should create database tables according to that only. just follow keep it simple concept while creating your database tables.

Comment: @KanmaniSelvan Please Update your question by inserting your above comment that you wish to create a forum and all... so everyone can see whats your real question is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relational databases don't have the concept of row order. If you care about the order that results are printed in a query, you must use the `ORDER BY` clause to specify the ordering based on the query data.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to remove the records which are after the record that you want to insert. There's no way to enter the data in specified order. However, for querying the table, you can use orderby.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially update every id after your location, making the new entry have an id of 3 in this case.